# What does (NodeJS) Express provide over just using Connect?

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

What does Express provide over just using Connect?

Most of the features of Express seem to be features of Connect.

Is there a list of what Express provides?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What does Express provide over just
>   using Connect?

Higher level of abstraction (web framework centric), template engines, view rendering.

> Is there a list of what Express
>   provides?

I would say Express [guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) lists quite good summary of it's features with examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Connect has routing, auth, etc. and the template engines work without express.  Many features in the guide are just features of Connect.  Express just seems to load template files from disk and use a template engine to render them.  Am I missing something big here?

Comment: I would say that Connect's purpose is to offer quick and simple (modular) web server features from the lower level point of view than Express which is more like a web framework with API crafted for making websites. Their functionality may overlap but target audience is somewhat different.